# following facebook login: setReadPermissions and registerCallback giving me error

Tags: facebook, authentication

trying to use FB login, followed their steps, but Android Studio gives me error: Cannot resolve methods .setReadPermissions and .registerCallback...

am new to this development and tech world... please, help! What am I doing wrong? Looked through many Q&A here, but none is giving me answers. Help much appreciated. Thanks!

I am trying to build a simple OCR app, with FB, Google logins and one independent register button. Code for registration class as follows:

public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
private static final String TAG = "AndroidClarified";

EditText et_username, et_password, et_cpassword, et_email;
RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
RadioButton radioSexButton;
Button btn_register, btnFBLogin, google_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    try {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }

    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();

    google_button = findViewById(R.id.google_button);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new 
    GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)

         .requestIdToken(getResources().getString(R.string.web_client_id))
         .requestEmail()
         .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    et_username = findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    et_password = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
    et_cpassword = findViewById(R.id.et_cpassword);
    et_email = findViewById(R.id.et_email);

    radioSexGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    final int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioSexButton = findViewById(selectedId);


    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String username = et_username.getText().toString();
            String password = et_password.getText().toString();
            String confirm_password = et_cpassword.getText().toString();
            String email = et_email.getText().toString();

            if (username.equals("") || password.equals("") || 
               confirm_password.equals("") || email.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields Required", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (password.equals(confirm_password)) {
                    boolean checkUsername = 
                   databaseHelper.CheckUsername(username);
                    if (checkUsername) {
                        boolean insert = databaseHelper.Insert(username, 
                   password, email);
                        if (insert) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                  "Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            et_username.setText("");
                            et_password.setText("");
                            et_cpassword.setText("");
                            et_email.setText("");
                        }
                        if (!isValidEmail(et_email.getText().toString())) { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username already taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
            return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
        }
    });

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    btnFBLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnFBLogin);
    List permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday", "gender");
    btnFBLogin.performClick();
    btnFBLogin.setReadPermissions(permissionNeeds);

    btnFBLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                        JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                        try {
                            if (json != null) {
                                String text = "<b>Name :</b> " + json.getString("name") + "<br><br><b>Email :</b> " + json.getString("email") + "<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> " + json.getString("link");
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d("fb_login_sdk", "callback cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Log.d("fb_login_sdk", "callback onError");
        }
    });

google_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 101);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 101:
                try {
                    // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
                    // a listener.
                    Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                    GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    String idToken = account.getIdToken();
                    onLoggedIn(account);
                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
                }
                break;
        }
}

private void onLoggedIn(GoogleSignInAccount mGoogleSignInAccount) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ProfileActivity.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT, mGoogleSignInAccount);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    if (GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Already Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onLoggedIn(account);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Not logged in");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: maybe you need show your full code, in manifest and in your main_activity

Comment: thank you for responding. since yesterday been trying to resolve this methods issue, but cannot. did everything required by FB, provided hash keys, got client ID, manifest and strings all in order...